# Ansible skipping playbook at first attempt on multiple-play playbook file

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook:

```yml
- import_playbook: "infrastructure/infrastructure.yml"
- import_playbook: "application/application.yml"
```

Inside these playbooks there are other playbooks being invoked, what happens is that in a specific moment one playbook will be executed in the `application.yml` pointed to `cicd_servers` group, and it will be skipped unintentionally.

See my inventory below:

```
[cicd_servers] 
sig-cicd-01 ansible_connection=local
```

This playbook in specific is that one below:

```yml
---
- hosts: cicd_servers   
    gather_facts: false   
    remote_user: ansible   
    connection: local

  roles:
    - application/os_setup
    - application/jdk_install
    - infrastructure/jenkins_install
    - infrastructure/maven_install
    - infrastructure/scm_install
    - infrastructure/soapui_install
    - database/sqlplus-install

################### cicd server applications ############
- hosts: cicd_servers   
    become: true   
    remote_user: ansible   
    connection: local   
  
    roles:
    - application/fmw_cicd_conf
    - application/fmw_performance_conf
```

I don't know why it's skipping only this host, I tried also to remove the parameters `ansible_connection=local` from the inventory and `connection: local` from the playbook to the DNS Name of the machine, and it doesn't work as well.

**Note**: If I just play again the same playbook it won't skip these tasks, that is, it only does not work at first attempt.

**Note2**: If I comment a few playbooks before it, it executes successfully at first attempt, but I need to get it as it should be.

**Note3**: I'm using ansible 2.9.10 version.

Below I registered 2 outputs with verbose (`-vvvv`) to try to identify something, but the output in the part being skipped doesn't say nothing.

```
output_1 (success)
PLAY [cicd_servers] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers
Thursday 21 January 2021  13:34:33 +0000 (0:00:21.729)       0:01:55.599 ******
included: /home/ansible/workspace_VFPT/roles/application/os_setup/tasks/infra.yml for sig-cicd-01.mgm.mw.sat.stp.vodafone.pt
Thursday 21 January 2021  13:34:33 +0000 (0:00:00.063)       0:01:55.663 ******
<sig-cicd-01.mgm.mw.sat.stp.vodafone.pt> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
```

```
output_2 (failed)

PLAY [cicd_servers] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY [cicd_servers] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

If you guys have any idea what is causing it, please let me know.

Comment: Is `sig-cicd-01` a localhost machine or why would you include `ansible_connection=local`? Generally it is advisable to try to always use FQDN for host definitions.

Comment: Exactly, the sig-cicd-01 is a localhost machine, I'm using `ansible_connection=local` intentionally.

Even though I tried to replace it for FQDN and it skips at first attempt of playbook's execution too.

Comment: do you have a DNS service running on that machine? Or do you have a host->ip reference setup in `/etc/hosts`? Without that services will be confused what `sig-cicd-01` really is.

Comment: I've a DNS service running.  `sig-cicd-01` is the FQDN, the DNS Suffix is not included in the name because it's already configured at network level of the machine.

I've already certified that these points related to network are working.

Notice that I've got success from the second attempt onwards of playbook's execution, the behaviour above only happens in the first attempt.